# Which version of Java supports the -command option?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclim

I'm attempting to use spacemacs, elipse and eclimd for editing with autocompletion. However, eclimd is attempting to start the java server with the `-command ping` option. My version of Java does not support that option. I have been unable to find this option in the documentation. Is it deprecated? Which version of Java supports it?

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -d64 -command ping -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace -XX:+UseG1GC -Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -jar /snap/eclipse/current/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar --launcher.suppressErrors -debug -clean -refresh -application org.eclim.application
Unrecognized option: -command
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No version of Java supports `-command`.

That option is supposed to be an argument for [`eclim`](http://eclim.org/eclimd.html), not for `java`

```
eclim -command ping
```

or presumably something like

```
java -d64 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace -XX:+UseG1GC -Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -jar /snap/eclipse/current/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar --launcher.suppressErrors -debug -clean -refresh -application org.eclim.application -command ping
```

Either you've configured something wrong, or something has a bug.

Comment: The command as OrangeDog edited it runs correctly from the command line. This does not solve my problem but eliminates java as a source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `-cmd`.

But maybe you are talking about a new feature in Java **11**. You can now do:

```
java HelloWorld.java
```

Meaning: when you have a "single file class", with a main method, you can sidestep invoking javac first, to then run java with the class name. Instead, you can do the above and directly "run+compile" a .java file.

That feature was added with [JEP 330](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330).